# Put a frame in a tabView using customTkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I've been trying to put a frame into a tabview of customTKinter, but the frame doesn't respond to the width and height.
This is my code:

```
class MyApp:
    def FillFirstTab(self, tab):
        frame = CTkFrame(master=tab, corner_radius=10,
                         border_width=2, width=500, height=500)
        entry = CTkEntry(frame, placeholder_text="CTkEntry", width=200)

        xImg = xCircleSmall()

        btn = CTkButton(frame, text="Click Me", image=CTkImage(dark_image=xImg.getObject(), light_image=xImg.getObject()),
                        command=buttonEvent, corner_radius=10, border_width=0, border_color="#000000")
        entry.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=1, anchor="center")
        frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        # Use configure to set the width and allow the frame to expand
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.app = CTk()
        self.app.title("My App")

        self.app.geometry(str(width) + "x" + str(height))
        set_appearance_mode("default")
        tabView = CTkTabview(self.app, width=width, height=height)
        tabView.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        tabView.add("Tab 1")
        tabView.add("Tab 2")
        tabView.add("Tab 3")
        self.FillFirstTab(tabView.tab("Tab 1"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    width = int(get_monitors()[0].width * 0.9)
    height = int(get_monitors()[0].height * 0.9)
    app = MyApp(width, height).app
    app.mainloop()
```

I changed a lot of stuffs in the frame configs

Answer (score 0):

By default, the size of the frame will be adjusted to fit all its children widgets when using `.pack()` or `.grid()` on those children widgets.  So the line `entry.pack(padx=10, pady=10)` will shrink the parent frame.

In order to keep the frame size when adding widgets using `pack()`, call `frame.pack_propagate(0)`. Or using `.place()` on the entry widget.